# Laravel 5.6 - disable errors

Tags: php, error-handling, laravel-5.6

I am running a laravel 5.6 application in localhost. In my .env file I've set the following values:

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=false
```

I've run the artisan command `php artisan config:clear`

Now I'm trying to test some api routes by deliberately generating sqlstate errors but I'm still seeing the full stacktrace of errors as json?

Obviously I wouldn't want to display all this info in production. So why are they still showing in my dev environment despite having APP_DEBUG set to false?

Answer (score 0):

looks like you have to restart the server after issuing the above commands for it to reflect any changes in env file.